# What do you need to do to insure that text bubbles are localization friendly in comics?

Tags: creative-writing, comics

What do you need to do to insure that text bubbles are localization friendly in comics? You gave a script and the artist filled the text bubbles she drew, but how do you know if the text bubbles are big enough for other languages? What are some precautions or things you should do in order to prevent having the issue where some text bubbles don't have enough spaces?

Comment: The only option I can really see is to put bubbles on a different layer than the rest of the comic. That way you can replace the bubbles by larger or smaller ones as needed. This is also a good idea because it lets you fix typo's and other issues more easily than if you had to edit a flattened image.

Comment: You should consider what languages you expect it to be translated into. If it's between different languages that all use the Roman alphabet, then lines may vary in length but text height and general layout is the same, so leaving a bit more space is probably enough. But very different writing systems may require different layouts. As towr says, separating the bubbles/text-boxes from the rest of it may be a better solution. As for going from left-to-right to right-to-left, that's a whole other set of issues.

Comment: If you actually know for a fact that it will be translated into other languages because you already have a publisher and they have told you that it will be translated, then they will have resources/people who are experts in this and can tell you. But if you don't know that it will be translated...just don't worry about it for now. It's probably better to cross bridges like this when you get to them, when right now you really need to just be focusing on making the best story you can.